# How to Disable Hardware SPI Chip Enable/Chip Select on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, spi, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm setting up a Raspberry Pi 4b with a number of Adafruit chips, and thus have used their [CircuitPython](https://circuitpython.org) library to control SPI communication. They've conveniently set up a way to use any GPIO pins as chip selects, but as a result I had no idea that there are two hardware chip selects on the Raspi (CE0 and CE1 on GPIO8 and GPIO7 respectively). I have already wired these pins (GPIO7&8) with the intention of using them as GPIO outputs, but I've noticed I GPIO8/CE0 is connected to the SPI clock.

Adafruit actually [mentions](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux/spi-sensors-devices) that the NO_CS flag doesn't work in their documentation, and I can't seem to find anything useful online.

**How can I disable the hardware CS pins?** I know the SPI_NO_CS flag in SPI_MODE is already a bug in the spi-bcm library, and I found [this](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/998863/) patch, but I'm not sure if it would work (I think CircuitPython utilizes a hardware CS?), let alone how to apply it.

Comment: You may have better luck asking this on [raspberrypi.se].